# trying to have characters generate on screen and walk to a location

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am making a game where I have a back ground image of a neighborhood and  each location has a different amount of customers that are generated to walk on sidewalks and have them all walk to a specific location (like a stand or cart that sells stuff) after they get to location I want them to interact with the cart but if another customer is already in the sale interaction then the others get in line in order of arrival. then walk away after transaction then walk off screen. Any information on how I can do this and what game engine would be needed?

Comment: I think maybe your question was closed because you didn't ask a _specific_ question which related to a programming issue which you were facing.  "How can I do this?" doesn't get as much traction here as "I tried this, and it didn't work.  I expected A, but B occurred."  Can you think of how to restate your problem like that?  What have you tried?  How didn't it work?

Comment: Well my issue is that I am not sure where to start with creating something like that. My main question with this is does anyone know if I should look into AndEngine or Libgdx for this or maybe someone know off hand how to exactly do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moving to a location is easy, you simply do:

```
int xDif = newposX - posX;
int yDif = newPosY - posY;

if(xDif > 1) posX++;
if(xDif < 1) posX--;
if(yDif > 1) posY++;
if(yDif < 1) posY--;
```

well.. that's the basic syntax, you would have to tweak it to make it work for you, but i'm not sure how you would do the interaction part..

Comment: ok, thanks. Yeah I just have a scene where there is a stand and am trying to have customers generate and start from 2 points on the screen and all walk to one location